# How to setup a mongodb with php XAMPP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a beginner to mongoDB, I want to learn mongoDB. So I read few tutorials and tried to configure mongoDB in my local machine, for that I have downloaded mondoDB's php_mongo.dll file and placed that on my local machine into the path "php/ext/php_mongo.dll" and after that I added this code "extension = php_mongo.dll" to php.ini file, after that I am trying run my XAMPP server but immediately it is showing the below error :

```
C:xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll is either not designed to run on Windows 
or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the 
original installation media or contact your system administrator or 
the software vendor for support.
```

after that somehow Apache server has been started And when I try to run the application on browser by URL http://localhost/mongoapp/index.php then it is throwing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoapp\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoapp\index.php on line 3
```

File: index.php

```
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully";
// select a database
$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";
```

My php version is "PHP Version 7.0.8". hope someone helps, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your phpinfo if mongodb is loaded.
2. Download mongodb from "https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community" and install.
3. Check your architecture in phpinfo match with mongodb.
   ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­